# Como excluir linhas de uma planilha, após realizar um filtro utilizando VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Estou com dificuldades para excluir as linhas resultantes de um filtro de texto em uma tabela. Gravei uma macro que resultou no seguinte código:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$161").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _  
  "=*EXT-11198*", Operator:=xlAnd  
Rows("30:200").Select  
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp  
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$139").AutoFilter Field:=2"
```

Funcionou apenas para aquela tabela específica, quando aplico em outra tabela com quantidade diferentes de registros ou a macro exclui registros a mais ou a menos.

Acredito que inserindo uma rotina que conte as linhas resultantes do filtro e exclua somente essas linhas resolva o problema.

Comment: Você está aplicando o filtro até a linha 161, portanto, naturalmente, se outa planilha tiver um tamanho maior, o filtro não vai afetar (como você mesmo disse). Além disso, Você está apagando da 30 até a 200. Qual é o parâmetro para apagar esse intervalo de linhas?

Comment: Calcular a última linha é fácil, mas a segunda parte depende do motivo de você querer excluir especificamente as linhas filtradas 30 a 200.

Comment: A seleção até a linha 200 foi aleatória, o que preciso é selecionar todas as linhas que contém um código, nesse caso "EXT-11198" e excluí-las antes de processar o restante da macro.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que o range que você está tentando excluir é variável, então antes de excluir você precisa descobrir quais são essas linhas usando a propriedade `UsedRange`.

```
' aplicar filtro
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$161").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _  
  "=*EXT-11198*", Operator:=xlAnd  

' pegar a área filtrada exceto o cabeçalho
Set area_filtrada = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)

' excluir a área filtrada
area_filtrada.Delete Shift:=xlUp

' exibir todos os dados
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
```